# button image upload in bootstrap,jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

i need to create a button with width 55 and height 45. initially the button should contain some default image. then when the user wants to change it, he can choose an image from his computer by selecting this button and once it is selected the image should be set that button and whenever we hover a mouse it should display change and we select it again we are able to change an image to it. how to do it. Is anybody know this. plz help me.
for ex: in scratch website https://scratch.mit.edu, after login,in profile page you can see this image button

Comment: Hi! Have you written any code in a' attempt to solve this yourself? if so, please include it here, also, your question is a tad confusing, could you perhaps elaborate it a bit?

Comment: i have not written. i am new to it

Comment: for ex: in scratch website https://scratch.mit.edu, after login,in profile page you can see this image button

Comment: I would recommend you either hire a free lance to do this or start with some tutorials about php/html/what ever you coding language you deem you need to solve the issue.